# Make Selected Mutiselect Items "selected"

Tags: array, php, select

I'm developing a theme settings panel for a new wordpress theme that have an option to exclude categories from being shown in the loop. I managed to get the main functionality to work, using a mutilselect box and saving the values as array ...

```
<?php $cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name'); ?>
<select name="<?php echo $option['id']; ?>[]" id="<?php echo $option['id']; ?>" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="0">None (don't exclude anything)</option>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat_list ) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat_list->cat_ID; ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $cat_list->cat_ID ); ?>><?php echo $cat_list->cat_name; ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

however I can't understand how check every item in `foreach()` loop if its value matches one value in the stored values array, then apply `selected="selected"`  if it returns true to it. I understand `selected()` wp function but don't understand how to make use of it in this case ( multiple values inside `foreach()` loop ).

Any help will be appreciated, I'm a n00b so forgive me if it's a stupid question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `$selected` variable contains an array of values for the currently selected items?

You can't use selected in this case (with multi select boxes) because it only compares two strings.  It won't test to see if the value is in an array.  Instead, use a ternary statement and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php 
foreach ($cats as $cat_list ) { 
$selected = in_array( $cat_list->cat_ID, $selected ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : '';    
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat_list->cat_ID; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $cat_list->cat_name; ?></option> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: He is asking about the core function :)

Comment: @Christopher Thank you very much, this solved my situation. I'm a php noob, that's why I couldn't find the suitable way myself. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but still the answer was not answered using the core function...

Here it is:

```
$cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name'); ?>
<select name="<?php echo $option['id']; ?>[]" id="<?php echo $option['id']; ?>" multiple="multiple">
<option value="0">None (don't exclude anything)</option>
<?php foreach ( $cats as $cat_list ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat_list->cat_ID; ?>" <?php selected( true, in_array($cat_list->cat_ID, $selected ) ); ?>><?php echo $cat_list->cat_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Make sure `$selected` is an array of course that contains selected category ids.

Answer (score 0):

The Q is not stupid. Imo just the extremly confusing way it's documented. I also remember that there's somewhere in the codex written, that using `selected()` and similar stuff is a must(!). I don't aggree.

Anyway: `selected( 'one_value', 'val_to_compare_with', true );`

Comment: thank you kaiser, I just wanted to achieve the same result but with an array of values instead of a single value. Christopher's answer is what I was seeking for. Thank you, I appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simpler:

```
<?php 
foreach ($cats as $cat_list ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat_list->cat_ID; ?>" <?php selected( in_array($cat_list->cat_ID, $selected ) ); ?>><?php echo $cat_list->cat_name; ?></option> 
<?php } 
?>
```

Here, `$selected` variable contains an array of values for the currently selected items.